# How do I pass a numerical value from .erb to PHP?

Tags: php, ruby

I have a a variable in a .erb file:

```
<% var_1 = (basket.to_f_withvat).to_money * 100 %>
```

From this assignment the `var_1` variable stores a value of 5000.

I now want to pass this value 5000 to a separate PHP page.

I have tried something like:

```
http://mysite.co.uk/page.php?var_1">Link</a></p>
```

but this doesn't return the numerical value when I use echo in `page.php`. It just prints out the string 'total'.

I'm new to query strings so I'm missing something simple.

Comment: `http://mysite.co.uk/page.php?var_1=5` var_1 is the name, right? So where's the value?

Comment: You can't just use "var_1" in a URL, you have to also give its value: `http://mysite.co.uk/page.php?var_1=5000">Link</a></p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use "`var_1`" in a URL, you have to also give its value:

```
http://mysite.co.uk/page.php?var_1=5000">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: I see but what if it gets its value from the (basket.to_f_withvat).to_money method

Comment: Then you use that to create your link. Because you're using ERB it's possible you're using ERB with Rails, but you could be using it standalone or with Sinatra. You didn't tell us enough to help you very much.

Comment: sorry, im using it stand alone. Please could you help me